# how to align marker to center of the image lists HTML

Tags: html, css

i have this code.

```
          <ul style="list-style-type:square">
            <li><img src="Files/Images/001.png"></li>
            <li><img src="Files/Images/002.png"></li>
            <li><img src="Files/Images/003.png"></li>
        </ul>
```

the marker seems to be at the align at the bottom of the image, how can align it to the center?

[image]

Comment: can you add the whole markup ...

Comment: im justing those pictures for practice

Answer (score 3):

You can remove bullets and use `:before` pseudo element instead with `Flexbox` for vertical align.

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li:before {
  content: "■";
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why is the list-type-style all squares? I want to use different ones on each list but the code works fine. thanks

Comment: @Dr.DOOM Because i set `content: "■"` but you can change that for each `ul` or `li`

Comment: how? i want to use different type like circles, disk, and for ordered lists as well

Comment: You can use HTML special characters or some icon fonts like font awesome, or images.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the content of your `li` tags with a span, then apply a CSS relative position to it.

Your stylesheet would be:

```
ul span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px; /* to adapt to the size of your image */
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><span><img src="Files/Images/001.png"></span></li>
  <li><span><img src="Files/Images/002.png"></span></li>
  <li><span><img src="Files/Images/003.png"></span></li>
</ul>
```

I don't have your images, but if your images have different heights, you would need to define a specific position for each one of them. You would then have:
    ul span {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    .li1 {
      top: 25px; /* whatever the size of the first image is */
    }
    etc…

And your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="li1"><img src="Files/Images/001.png"></span></li>
  <li><span class="li2"><img src="Files/Images/002.png"></span></li>
  <li><span class="li3"><img src="Files/Images/003.png"></span></li>
</ul>
```

I don't see why you have that `td` tag by the way.

Answer (score -1):

To align a `li` marker you need to align an element inside the `li`.
This is due to `::marker` is anchored to the element inside the `li`.

```css
li {
    width: 350px;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
            aliqua... 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```